# How to count how many times a specific value appeared on each columns and group by range

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, pivot, unpivot

I'm new on postgres and I have a question:

I have a table with 100 columns. I need to count the values from each columns and count how many times they appeared, so I can group then based on the range that they fit

I have a table like this(100 columns)

```
+------+------+------+------+------+---------+--------+
| Name | PRB0 | PRB1 | PRB2 | PRB3 | ....... | PRB100 |
+------+------+------+------+------+---------+--------+
| A    |   15 |   6  |   47 |   54 |   ..... |      8 |
| B    |   25 |   22 |   84 |   86 |   ..... |     76 |
| C    |   57 |   57 |   96 |   38 |   ..... |     28 |
+------+------+------+------+------+---------+--------+
```

And need the output to be something like this

```
+------+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-----+-----------------+--+
| Name | Count 0 to 20 | Count 21 to 40 | Count 41 to 60 | Count 61 to 70 | ... | Count 81 to 100 |  |
+------+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-----+-----------------+--+
| A    |             5 |             46 |             87 |             34 | ... |              98 |  |
| B    |             5 |              2 |             34 |             56 | ... |              36 |  |
| C    |             7 |             17 |             56 |             78 | ... |              88 |  |
+------+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-----+-----------------+--+
```

For Name A we have:

- 5 times the number between 0 and 20 apeared
- 46 times the number between 21 and 40 appeared
- 86 times the number between 41 and 60 appeared

Basicaly I need something like the function COUNTIFS that we have on Excel. On excel we just need to especify the range of columns and the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could unpivot with a lateral join, then aggregate:

```
select
    name,
    count(*) filter(where prb between 0  and 20) cnt_00_20,
    count(*) filter(where prb between 21 and 50) cnt_21_20,
    ...,
    count(*) filter(where prb between 81 and 100) cnt_81_100
from mytable t
cross join lateral (values(t.prb0), (t.prb1), ..., (t.prb100)) p(prb)
group by name
```

Note, however, that this still requires you to enumerate all the columns in the `values()` table constructor. If you want something fully dynamic, you can use json instead. The idea is to turn each record to a json object using `to_jsonb()`, then to rows with `jsonb_each()`; you can then do conditional aggregation.

```
select 
    name,
    count(*) filter(where prb::int between 0  and 20) cnt_00_20,
    count(*) filter(where prb::int between 21 and 50) cnt_21_20,
    ...,
    count(*) filter(where prb::int between 81 and 100) cnt_81_100
from mytable t
cross join lateral to_jsonb(t) j(js)
cross join lateral jsonb_each( j.js - 'name') r(col, prb)
group by name
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly. I did the first method by enumerate all the 100 columns. I will study this method line by line to understand each command line.